# determine most similar phrase using word2vec

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, word2vec

I try create a model which determine the most similar sentence for another sentence using word2vec.

The idea is to determine the most similar for a sentence, I created an average vector for the words composed this sentence.

Then, I should to predict the most similar sentence using embedding words.
My question is: How can I determine the best similar target sentence after created an average vector of source sentence?

Here the code :

```
import gensim
from gensim import utils
import numpy as np
import sys
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk import download
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)


download('punkt') #tokenizer, run once
download('stopwords') #stopwords dictionary, run once
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

def preprocess(text):
    text = text.lower()
    doc = word_tokenize(text)
    doc = [word for word in doc if word not in stop_words]
    doc = [word for word in doc if word.isalpha()] #restricts string to alphabetic characters only
    return doc
############  doc content  -> num label     -> string label
#note to self: texts[XXXX] -> y[XXXX] = ZZZ -> ng20.target_names[ZZZ]

# Fetch ng20 dataset
ng20 = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all',
                          remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))
# text and ground truth labels
texts, y = ng20.data, ng20.target

corpus = [preprocess(text) for text in texts]

def filter_docs(corpus, texts, labels, condition_on_doc):
    """
    Filter corpus, texts and labels given the function condition_on_doc which takes
    a doc.
    The document doc is kept if condition_on_doc(doc) is true.
    """
    number_of_docs = len(corpus)
    print(number_of_docs)

    if texts is not None:
        texts = [text for (text, doc) in zip(texts, corpus)
                 if condition_on_doc(doc)]

    labels = [i for (i, doc) in zip(labels, corpus) if condition_on_doc(doc)]
    corpus = [doc for doc in corpus if condition_on_doc(doc)]

    print("{} docs removed".format(number_of_docs - len(corpus)))

    return (corpus, texts, labels)

corpus, texts, y = filter_docs(corpus, texts, y, lambda doc: (len(doc) != 0))

def document_vector(word2vec_model, doc):
    # remove out-of-vocabulary words
    #print("doc:")
    #print(doc)
    doc = [word for word in doc if word in word2vec_model.vocab]
    return np.mean(word2vec_model[doc], axis=0)

def has_vector_representation(word2vec_model, doc):
    """check if at least one word of the document is in the
    word2vec dictionary"""
    return not all(word not in word2vec_model.vocab for word in doc)

corpus, texts, y = filter_docs(corpus, texts, y, lambda doc: has_vector_representation(model, doc))

x =[]
for doc in corpus: #look up each doc in model

    x.append(document_vector(model, doc))


X = np.array(x) #list to array

model.most_similar(positive=X, topn=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the cosine distance. It's implemented in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html).

For better efficiency, you can implement it yourself and precompute the norms of vectors in `X`:

```py
X_norm = np.linalg.norm(X, axis=1).expand_dims(0)
```

Calling `expand_dims` ensures that dimensions got broadcasted. Then for vectors `Y`, you can get the most similar, you can get the most similar:

```
def get_most_similar_in_X(Y):
    Y_norm = np.linalg.norm(Y, axis=1).expand_dims(1)
    similarities = np.dot(Y, X.T) / Y_norm / X_norm
    return np.argmax(distances, axis=2)
```

And you get indices of vectors in `X` that are most similar to vectors in `Y`.